# How to automatically wrap JavaFX 2 ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2, multiline

How can I make an auto wrap ListView (multiline when the text is too long) in JavaFX 2? I know that if I put a `\n` to the string, it will be multiline, but the content is too dynamic.

Or is there a good way to put `\n` to the String after every `xyz` pixel length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a TextArea in the ListCell.graphicProperty().  This is usually used to set an icon in a list cell but can just as easy to set to any Node subclass.

Comment: You can also call [setEditable(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setEditable%28boolean%29) on the `TextArea` to make it read only if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the exact code how I did it finally.

```
    ListView<String> messages = new ListView<>();
    messages.relocate(10, 210);
    messages.setPrefSize(this.getPrefWidth() - 20, this.getPrefHeight() - 250);
    messages.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            final ListCell cell = new ListCell() {
                private Text text;

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!isEmpty()) {
                        text = new Text(item.toString());
                        text.setWrappingWidth(messages.getPrefWidth());
                        setGraphic(text);
                    }
                }
            };

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I found this code produced unintended behavior in JavaFX8. Slightly modifying `if  (!isEmpty)` to `if (empty || item == null)` works for this version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create additional controls such as `TextArea` or `Text`. It is enough to just `setWrapText(true)` of the `ListCell` **and** `setPrefWidth(50.0)` or so. It will be automatically rewrapped on resize.
Here is my working code in Kotlin:

```
    datasets.setCellFactory()
    {
        object : ListCell<Dataset>()
        {
            init
            {
                isWrapText = true
                prefWidth = 50.0
            }

            override fun updateItem(item: Dataset?, empty: Boolean)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty)

                text = item?.toString()
            }
        }
    }
```

By the way, this is how I made it to correctly wrap CamelCase words:

```
replace(Regex("(?<=\\p{javaLowerCase})(?=\\p{javaUpperCase})|(?<=[_.])"), "\u2028")
```

Here `\u2028` is the Unicode soft line break character, which javaFX respects.